# Is there a way to get the final system of equations sent by cvxpy to the solver?

Tags: cvxpy, convex-optimization

If I understand correctly, cvxpy converts our high-level problem description to the standard canonical form before it is sent to a solver.

By the standard form I mean the form that can be used for the descent algorithms, so, for instance, it would convert all the absolute values in the objective to be a difference of two positive numbers with some new constraints, etc.

Wondering if its possible to see what the reduction looked like for a problem I specify in cvxpy?
For instance, lets say I have the following problem:

```
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cp

x = cp.Variable(2)
L = np.asarray([[1,2],[2,3]])
P = L.T @ L

constraints = []
constraints.append(x >= [-10, -10])
constraints.append(x <= [10, 10])

obj = cp.Minimize(cp.quad_form(x, P) - [1, 2] * x)
prob = cp.Problem(obj, constraints)
prob.solve(), prob.solver_stats.solver_name
(-0.24999999999999453, 'OSQP')
```

So, I would like to see the actual arguments (P, q, A, l, u) being sent to the OSQP solver https://github.com/oxfordcontrol/osqp-python/blob/master/module/interface.py#L278

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

From looking at the [documentation](https://www.cvxpy.org/api_reference/cvxpy.problems.html?highlight=get%20problem%20data#cvxpy.problems.problem.Problem.get_problem_data), it seems you can do this using the command `get_problem_data` as follows:

```
data, chain, inverse_data = prob.get_problem_data(prob.solver_stats.solver_name)
```

I have not tried it, and it says it output depends on the particular solver and the solver chain, but it may help you!